# WPF Focus on "run" element

Tags: wpf, styling

I would like to change the background of the **`Run`** that has the focus in a `FlowDocument` in a `RichTextBox`.
I would like to provide to my users a visual cue as to which `Run` element they are currently editing and I think a light background would be the best way for my application.

I see that the `Run` has `Focusable` (which I set to true), `IsFocused`, `FocusVisualStyle`, `GotFocus`, etc. but none of those properties or events seam to work.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a data trigger to get the effect you want. Here's an example:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type RichTextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true"> 
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGrey" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers> 
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I am interested in styling the Run not the RichTextBox. The RichTextBox is easy.

Comment: What do you expect to see differently? With the example above the entire background of the text area is changed (I just tried it out). Which transient (meaning a property that is not persisted with the FlowDocument since it is based on focus and not on something the user entered) visual property are you wanting to change?

Comment: I am not sure what to respond, because you seamed to have answered your own question. I want to change the background of the RUN that currently has focus. having the entire richTextBox's background change is useless. the user still has no idea whether when they start typing their text is going to end up in the current run or in a new run.